# Two jQuery UI Dialog's have the same position values but are not displaying in top of each other

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog

I have two jQuery UI dialogs which are basically the same. They have the same positions. The problem is that they are displayed in the wrong positions in the browser, not 200 &200 from top & left of the viewport, plus they are not on top of each other.

The x position seems correct but not their y values.

What am I missing?

[See JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/UvUga/1/)

**Addition:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $( "#one" ).dialog({
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }, position: [200,200]
                });

//          $( "#two" ).dialog({
//                  closeOnEscape: false,
//                  open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }, position: [200,200]
//          });

        });

  </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div id="one" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;border: 1px solid red;background-color: #ddd">Hello</div>
<div id="two" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;border: 1px solid red;background-color: #ccc">Hello 2</div>




</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the `position: relative` that uid dialog sets.

http://jsfiddle.net/bJEgR/1/

Since I've not worked with this particular plugin before, I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not, but as a proof of concept, it shows that it is the `position: relative` setting. I used to Firebug to inspect the css.

```
$( "#one" ).dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        $(".ui-dialog").css('position','absolute');
        $(".ui-dialog").css('top','100px');  
        $(".ui-dialog").css('left','100px');
    },
    position: [200,200]
});
$( "#two" ).dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        $(".ui-dialog").css('position','absolute');
        $(".ui-dialog").css('top','100px');  
        $(".ui-dialog").css('left','100px');
    },
    position: [200,200]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the dialogs with a div which has a declared height seems to fix it. I don't know if this is a bug.